# How to build a webform with a slider field

Tags: webforms, javascript

The Webform module itself doesn't (yet?) support the html5 `<input type="range">` element, which isn't really cross-browser compatible yet anyway.  I suppose right now (2013) we're stuck using a Javascript solution, and the most popular solution in the Drupal world seems to be the JQuery UI slider component, via the sliderfield module. However, the module page and issue queue makes no mention of integration with Webform.

I'm wondering if there is a module I've somehow overlooked that does offer slider/range widgets for Drupal Webforms, and if not, what is the most recommendable way to implement one, that could be shared and or turned into a module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will actually need to create a custom module to create a new webform component. This link contains more information on how to get it done http://jamestombs.co.uk/2012-09-24/create-new-webform-element-drupal-7

Comment: Thanks Fahad, that post looks just like what I was looking for!